# Is it possible for "cruddy" computers cases to have faulty on/off buttons?

Tags: power, power-supply, case

I can't quite pinpoint this problem.

About 6 months ago I purchased an incredibly cheap computer case, and an incredibly cheap power supply from NewEgg.

After I overloaded the powersupply 'til the point it was literally smoking. I removed some of the extra video cards (this was a gpu cluster computer) and proceeded as usual.

This one incredibly annoying thing kept happening. Whenever I would go to plug in my computer monitor to the back of the computer... there was a 50/50 chance the machine would shut off right away.

I immediately thought it must be the power supply. Mainly because I had driven it to the point of smoking. So I removed the power supply and replaced it with a high quality, gold+ Antec PSU (and changed out the motherboard, cpu and ram while I was at it).

Low and behold, the computer persists to switch off miraculously simply by touching it.

Again, this does not happen all of the time. I have noticed it depends where I touch it exactly. Towards the top of the case (where the power and rest buttons reside) is where it is most vulnerable.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with a short/ground.  Off topic for SF though.

Comment: `incredibly cheap`: In other words, you wasted money on stuff you had/have to buy again in decent quality. Congratulations.

Comment: Agreed, a short in the wiring.electrical, possibly a bad connection between the MB and PSU. Not a power button issue, that takes ~5 seconds to turn a computer off.

Comment: What's the maxim? Computer Power Supplies: Buy Cheap, Buy Twice.

Comment: that actually applies to almost anything, and is a great rule of thumb / reason to get fancy things.

Comment: @SvenW - Am I to understand you advocate buying always the most expensive ones? "Cheap" is what drives the world forward.

Comment: @Rook: Not necessarily the most expensive ones, but definitely not the cheapest ones. If you want to built stuff cheaper than other vendors, you have to cut your costs somewhere, and it's surely not your profit you are going to cut, so the quality will be lower. In the case of "incredibly cheap" it's nearly always the case that the quality is far too low. I also disagree strongly that "cheap drives the world forward", because the opposite is true in the long run, with people buying crappy stuff with money they don't have that ends up in landfills anyway, destroying both economy and environment

Comment: I too was put off by SvenW's comments. I am looking for answers, not life suggestions. Keep your economical ideas to yourself. Incredibly cheap to me may be beyond affordable to you. They are only words. Now answer my question. Who said anything about profit anyways? I was doing this as a charitable effort. @jscott and Chris S, thank you both for your input.

Comment: @tombull89, if you were reading, I clearly stated "I removed the power supply and replaced it with a high quality, gold+ Antec PSU" and the problem still persists.

Comment: @SvenW - Actually, you might want to check your economy and history books. You're wrong on several points.

Comment: @darkaspitch. Its not beyond the realms of fancy that when el-cheapo power supply blew/overloaded, its taken out every single component inside the computer. psu created problems can often be a total pig to fix. I'd imagine that's why multiple people are recommending never buying rubbish ones. I know at least 3 of the 5 most long-drawn out and ultimately expensive computer problems i've encountered started with psu issues or power surges.

Comment: @darkAsPitch, I meant that as a general idea, not one just targed to you.

Comment: does it "shut down gracefully?" Does it appear as though the OS received a shutdown signal? Does it takes approx. 4 seconds between "merely touching it" and the shutdown?

Comment: @horatio, thank you, that is probably the best question here. No, it shuts down immediately, but the funny thing is... it's power button flashes on and off (every second or so) while the computer still seems to be "on" in a sense.

Comment: what is the case model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, considering how simple modern computer power switches are. possible but unlikely. The good news is its a simple thing to just bridge the two contacts for power to test it. Bad news is this could indicate a fault somewhere else.I would try running the system with the power switch unplugged, using something else (I have switches pulled from old cases 'in case' but i've switched on systems with a penny before).

I'd note computer cases, while metal, are painted so.. a short would be unusual.

Comment: Great idea, "try using the system with the power button unplugged", it was most definitely the power cable. I just didn't think to try that because, well, I couldn't turn it on (conventionally). Just as I had thought. A $1 piece of equipment was the only culprit in my cheapo system. No need to throw the baby out with the bathwater, I'm looking at you, SvenW **ಠ_ಠ**

Comment: well, it could be a short anywhere along there. shouldn't be too hard to visually inspect and patch or replace it. bonus points for replacing it with a knife switch ;). I've worked with some fun situations (caseless PCs, and junkyard revivals) so that was the obvious possibility

Comment: +1, however, I have seen bad power buttons quite a few times! Anything from the hinge (from button to case) gone to the spring inside - this can make them really flimsy and sensitive... so... I wouldn't rule it out!

Answer (score 1):

Does your psu have a short or surge protection circuit or switch? One thing you could test to see if it's a shorting issue is screw an earth to the inside of the top of the case, if it doesn't turn on at all then there's a short circuit somewhere on the case.. however I'd be surprised if this was the cause, if it was you'd probably feel the shock when you touched it.

Comment: Again. PSU was switched out and the problem persists. This had nothing to do with the PSU.

Comment: I was more suggesting it was an issue with the case shorting somewhere.